# Keyboard shortcut to select some text in a cell in Excel

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

I'd like to know the shortcut I must use to do a multiple selection of some text (not adjacent words) in a unique cell.
The reason is because I need to highlight some text of the same cell, and I currently have to do it selecting the text individually.
So it would be very helpful to find the shortcut to multiple select, as Ctrl + click usually works.
I used it time ago, but I don't remember how I did.
Please, could you help me

Thanks & regards
Susana

Comment: Are you using Excel for Mac?

Comment: Yes, excel for Mac. But I think it also happens for Windows

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to select non-adjacent words in a cell in Excel. If you need to format several non-adjacent words, you need to process them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the cmd key is your best bet.

I can't try it, i'm not in front of a computer now, but in most OS X programs and also in Word for Mac, the cmd key allows you to select different nonconsecutive strings of text.

Comment: Guess that's not working in Excel. Not even in the formula bar?

Comment: Yes, usually Cmd key works for other apps, but not in this case. That's why I wonder how to do it